# How to use Pandas Timestamp fold argument?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, fold

When playing around with timezone conversions and dst impact, I have a hard time figuring out Pandas implementation of the `fold` parameter of the `Timestamp` constructor. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html#) mentions:

> Due to daylight saving time, one wall clock time can occur twice when shifting from summer to winter time; fold describes whether the datetime-like corresponds to the first (0) or the second time (1) the wall clock hits the ambiguous time.

So far no surprise, but when I run the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

pre_fold = pd.Timestamp(datetime(2022,10,30,1,30,0), tz="CET")
in_fold_fold0 = pd.Timestamp(datetime(2022,10,30,2,30,0), tz="CET")
in_fold_fold1 = pd.Timestamp(datetime(2022,10,30,2,30,0), tz="CET", fold=1)
post_fold = pd.Timestamp(datetime(2022,10,30,3,30,0), tz="CET")

print(f"fold0: {in_fold_fold0.fold}")
print(f"fold1: {in_fold_fold1.fold}")

print(f"Pre CET fold:       {pre_fold}  ->  UTC {pre_fold.tz_convert(tz='UTC')}")
print(f"In CET fold, fold0: {in_fold_fold0}  ->  UTC {in_fold_fold0.tz_convert(tz='UTC')}")
print(f"In CET fold, fold1: {in_fold_fold1}  ->  UTC {in_fold_fold1.tz_convert(tz='UTC')}")
print(f"Post CET fold:      {post_fold}  ->  UTC {post_fold.tz_convert(tz='UTC')}")
```

the output is not as expected:

```
fold0: 0
fold1: 1
Pre CET fold:       2022-10-30 01:30:00+02:00  ->  UTC 2022-10-29 23:30:00+00:00
In CET fold, fold0: 2022-10-30 02:30:00+01:00  ->  UTC 2022-10-30 01:30:00+00:00
In CET fold, fold1: 2022-10-30 02:30:00+01:00  ->  UTC 2022-10-30 01:30:00+00:00
Post CET fold:      2022-10-30 03:30:00+01:00  ->  UTC 2022-10-30 02:30:00+00:00
```

Line 4 should be:

```
In CET fold, fold0: 2022-10-30 02:30:00+02:00  ->  UTC 2022-10-30 00:30:00+00:00
```

What am I missing here?

**PS:** Using python's `datetime` objects results in expected output:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

dt_pre_fold = datetime(2022,10,30,1,30,0, tzinfo=tz.gettz("CET"))
dt_in_fold_fold0 = datetime(2022,10,30,2,30,0, tzinfo=tz.gettz("CET"))
dt_in_fold_fold1 = datetime(2022,10,30,2,30,0, tzinfo=tz.gettz("CET"), fold=1)
dt_post_fold = datetime(2022,10,30,3,30,0, tzinfo=tz.gettz("CET"))

print(f"Pre CET fold:       {dt_pre_fold}  ->  UTC {dt_pre_fold.astimezone(tz.gettz('UTC'))}")
print(f"In CET fold, fold0: {dt_in_fold_fold0}  ->  UTC {dt_in_fold_fold0.astimezone(tz.gettz('UTC'))}")
print(f"In CET fold, fold1: {dt_in_fold_fold1}  ->  UTC {dt_in_fold_fold1.astimezone(tz.gettz('UTC'))}")
print(f"Post CET fold:      {dt_post_fold}  ->  UTC {dt_post_fold.astimezone(tz.gettz('UTC'))}")
```

Output:

```
Pre CET fold:       2022-10-30 01:30:00+02:00  ->  UTC 2022-10-29 23:30:00+00:00
In CET fold, fold0: 2022-10-30 02:30:00+02:00  ->  UTC 2022-10-30 00:30:00+00:00
In CET fold, fold1: 2022-10-30 02:30:00+01:00  ->  UTC 2022-10-30 01:30:00+00:00
Post CET fold:      2022-10-30 03:30:00+01:00  ->  UTC 2022-10-30 02:30:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the timezone info is not correctly specified:

```
# using your code
x = pd.Timestamp(datetime(2022,10,30,2,30,0), fold = 0, tz="CET")
x.tz_convert('UTC')
# Timestamp('2022-10-30 01:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

But if you use `from dateutil import tz`

```
x = pd.Timestamp(datetime(2022,10,30,2,30,0), fold = 0, tz=tz.gettz("CET"))
x.tz_convert('UTC')
# Timestamp('2022-10-30 00:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

It returns the correct value

Comment: I found that using `pytz.tz` with `datetime` objects has the same incorrect behaviour as I mentioned in the initial question. Actually bizarre that I didn't think of using `dateutil.tz` with Pandas' `Timestamp` (as I did for Python's `datetime`)...

Comment: @sTievie pandas is using pytz internally, so dateutil's tz giving the correct result here seems weird to me. It looks like a hack/workaround, giving the correct result for the wrong reason.

Comment: **Also:** even if timezone objects of `dateutil` are used to have correct behaviour when the `fold` parameter of a `Timestamp` object is set to 1, the value of `fold` seems to be ignored when converting back to Python's native `datetime` (using `to_pydatetime`). So the general remark of @FObersteiner "don't mix" holds...

Comment: I think the important point here is that you *must use* a dateutil timezone (or probably zoneinfo.ZoneInfo) to make fold work correctly. pytz just doesn't support it.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of circumvents the question but instead of using 'fold', you can localize a timestamp to a certain time zone and use the `ambiguous` keyword to specify if it should be the DST or the non-DST time, from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html):

> **ambiguous** [...]
> bool-ndarray where True signifies a DST time, False signifies a non-DST time (note that this flag is only applicable for ambiguous times)

So you could have done what you need like

```py
import pandas as pd

f0 = pd.Timestamp("2022-10-30 02:30:00").tz_localize("Europe/Berlin", ambiguous=True)
f1 = pd.Timestamp("2022-10-30 02:30:00").tz_localize("Europe/Berlin", ambiguous=False)

print(f0.tz_convert('UTC'))
print(f1.tz_convert('UTC'))
# 2022-10-30 00:30:00+00:00 # was DST, UTC+2
# 2022-10-30 01:30:00+00:00 # was non-DST, UTC+1
```

---

As to why 'fold' does not work properly, I think this goes back to the fact that `pandas` is still using `pytz` internally for time zone handling. **pytz does not support 'fold'**, it uses keyword 'is_dst' instead. You can find more info on that e.g. in [this blog post](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) by Paul Ganssle. There's also some hints deep [in the pandas src](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/efb262ff526b6f8810b3ad1f675ffdb919af343f/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L1368). In contrast, `dateutil`'s timezone *does* support 'fold', which is likely the reason why @ZLi 's solution works.

---

side notes:

- it is better to use actual [IANA time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to avoid any ambiguities the abbreviations might have
- don't mix native Python datetime and pandas' datetime, to avoid some of the rough edges of native Python datetime

Comment: Personally, I find `fold`= [0,1] more intuitive, since the value of `fold` can be seen as the number of times the corresponding naive datetime has occurred before.


I understand the explanation given for the `ambiguous`, but to me both occurrences of the naive datetime are ambiguous and therefore less intuitive, especially since you need to know which of both occurrences is DST (```True```) of non-DST (```False```)…


+1 for presenting a non-mixed (not mixing native Python `datetime` with pandas' `Timestamp`) solution.

Comment: @sTievie I think pandas devs should have implemented `fold` correctly instead of `ambiguous` - I find it more intuitive as well. But I don't know the details of the implementation, there tends to be a reason for things ^^

Comment: After a closer look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html) that reason might be that the devs wanted to do more with `ambiguous` than just `fold=0|1`, which makes sense since they implemented it in conversion context rather than an object creation context... Nevertheless the usage of `True|False` stays "ambiguous" ;-)

Comment: @sTievie yeah, "ambiguous" can do more than that, not like "do one thing and do it well" ;-) I'm thinking about raising an issue on the pandas github on this thing. Or you could do as well if you like

Comment: @ FObersteiner Feel free to do so...

Comment: @sTievie I've added some more info, think I found the reason of this odd behavior. Now I don't see much point in raising an issue anymore.